# Flutter getting the following error The return type 'List<Widget>' isn't a 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following error `The return type 'List<Widget>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.` It's happing on `_buildUserStatsSectionItems`

Here is my main widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(
      stream: userDoc,
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> snapshot,
      ) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: const [
              Text(
                "Loading",
                style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsTextStyle,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
        return _buildUserStatsSectionItems(snapshot.data);
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is the _buildUserStatsSectionItems

```
List<Widget> _buildUserStatsSectionItems(data) {
  return <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          data['totalTrainingSessions'].toString(),
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsTextStyle,
        ),
        const Text(
          'sessions',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsSubTextStyle,
        )
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          data['totalTrainingDays'].toString(),
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsTextStyle,
        ),
        const Text(
          'days',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsSubTextStyle,
        )
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          data['totalTrainingTime'].toString(),
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsTextStyle,
        ),
        const Text(
          'hours',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsSubTextStyle,
        )
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          data['dogsCount'].toString(),
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsTextStyle,
        ),
        const Text(
          'dogs',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: AppStyles.dashboardStatsSubTextStyle,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `_buildUserStatsSectionItems` is `List<Widget>`. Based on the [StreamBuilder documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncWidgetBuilder.html), the `AsyncWidgetBuilder` should return `Widget` - this is where the error comes from.

To resolve your issue, you should wrap your widgets inside `_buildUserStatsSectionItems` with `Wrap` or `Column`:

```
Widget _buildUserStatsSectionItems(data) {
  return Column(
    children: [...], // Add your current Widget list here
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but wrap or Column mess up the layout,  I'm just trying to return all Columns while keeping my row widget on the parent not the child

Comment: Could you use a Grid with only one row instead of all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

`StreamBuilder` apparently takes only one widget as return value from the builder.
Just wrap your function in a `Column / Row` like so:

```
return Column(children:_buildUserStatsSectionItems(snapshot.data));
```

or make your function return only one Widget.

Comment: The provided code example will throw an error. It should be `return Column(children: _buildUserStatsSectionItems(snapshot.data))`.